float/double is not working on qemu and spike for riscv-unknown-elf-gcc tool chain
float/double is not working on qemu for riscv-unknown-elf-gcc tool chain
it is giving me exception trap_illegal_instruction
I just tried running a simple program which has float in it, using riscv-unknown-elf-gcc tool chain
on qemu and spike. can anyone help resolving this error?

Is qemu configured for a RISC-V platform that supports floating-point instructions? Has the compiler been configured for the proper target architecture, such as rv32gc?

Are you using QEMU system emulation or usermode emulation? If system emulation, does your startup code correctly enable the FPU before jumping to C code?

There was a problem in the startup code previously i didn't enable fpu registers from bootcode. After enabling them it is working now.
